# Use dplyr::rename function in a for loop in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to understand how the `dplyr::rename` function works in a for loop work in R. In principle, I want to rename the column names of multiple data frames coming from another list.

Here is an example that fails, where I want to rename the first column of each dataset with a name coming from the `new.names` data set.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris1 <- iris
iris2 <- iris
iris3 <- iris

files <- list(iris1,iris2,iris3)

new.names <- c("change1","change2","change")
```

If I try this for loop it fails:

```
test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test[[i]] <- files[[i]] |> 
    dplyr::rename(new.names[i]=1)
}
test
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a loop you need to use `!! sym()` on the names names of the lefthand side as well as the walrus operator `:=`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris1 <- iris
iris2 <- iris
iris3 <- iris

files <- list(iris1,iris2,iris3)

new.names <- c("change1","change2","change")

test <- list()

test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test[[i]] <- files[[i]] |> 
    dplyr::rename(!! sym(new.names[i]) := 1)
}
test |>
  map(head) # for printing
#> [[1]]
#>   change1 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   change2 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   change Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1    5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2    4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3    4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4    4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5    5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6    5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

We can also do it without a `for` loop then we need the `new.names` list to be a list of lists and we can then use `purrr::map2()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris1 <- iris
iris2 <- iris
iris3 <- iris

files <- list(iris1,iris2,iris3)

new.names <- list(
  list(change1 = 1),
  list(change2 = 1),
  list(change = 1))

map2(files,
     new.names,
     ~ dplyr::rename(.x, !!! .y) %>% 
       head() # for printing
     )

#> [[1]]
#>   change1 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   change2 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   change Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1    5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2    4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3    4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4    4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5    5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6    5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Why does this work?

In dplyr we can construct calls as lists and then evaluate (or splice) them with `!!!`. This is what we do here.

`new.names` conains a list of list. Each sub-list has the new column name as name and the position of the old column as value.

So for one file we could do:

`dplyr::rename(files[[1]], !!! new.names[[1]]) |> head()`

If `new.names` would just be a simple list (without sub-lists) then the values wouldn't have a name and we would not be able to construct the call.

Finally we can also use `map2()` without constructing the call with a list of lists, but instead use a string:

```r
new.names <- c("change1", "change2", "change")

map2(files,
     new.names,
     ~ dplyr::rename(.x, !! sym(.y) := 1) %>% 
       head() # for printing
     )
```

The logic is the same as in the `for` loop: we turn the strings into names with `sym()` evaluate them with `!!` and use the walrus operatur `:=` instead `=`.

Comment: it looks great, but I am wondering what is the meaning of `!!!` in `dplyr::rename(.x, !!! .y)`

Comment: @LDT I added some explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is a different apporach using the function `setNames()`:

```
test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test[[i]] <- files[[i]] %>%  
    setNames(c(new.names[i], names(files[[i]])[-1]))
}

> test %>% lapply(head)
#[[1]]
#  change1 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#
#[[2]]
#  change2 Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2     4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3     4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4     4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5     5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6     5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#
#[[3]]
#  change Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1    5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2    4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3    4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4    4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5    5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6    5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dplyr::rename_with` in order to pass dynamically the renaming part as a function like this:

```
test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test[[i]] <- files[[i]] %>%
    dplyr::rename_with(function(x) { x <- new.names[i]; return(x) }, c(1) )

}
test
```

Please read `renames_with`'s [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html) regarding the parameters for both the specified function and tidy select.

In case you don't care about `dplyr::rename`, the most simple thing that you can do is:

```
test <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  
  test[i] <- files[i]
  
  names(test[[i]])[1] <- new.names[i]
}
test
```